# Multiple ajax requests kill django server

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-views, ajaxform

I have a single view which scrolls through user data. There are next and previous buttons to scroll. When user presses next, ajax sends the user id to the django view and displays the data. 
If user clicks the next button two or three times consecutively (which they usually do), the calls get aborted and server is killed.

```
$("#new").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/new/',
        data:{
               csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success:searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        $('#myForm').html(data);
     }
```

This is the view.

```
def master_detail_next(request):
    def decrement_voucher_id(form_id):
        voucher_id = str(int(form_id) - 1).zfill(4)
        return voucher_id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_id = request.POST['voucher_id']
        voucher_id = decrement_voucher_id(form_id)
        voucher_id = get_decremented_voucher_id(voucher_id)
    else:
        voucher_id = ''

    # Inline forms
    author = TmpPlInvoice.objects.get(voucher_id=voucher_id)
    author_form = TmpForm(instance=author)

    BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TmpPlInvoice, TmpPlInvoicedet,
                                    exclude=('emp_id', 'voucher', 'lineitem', 'id',),
                                    form=TmpFormDetForm, )
    formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
    totalform = TmpFormTotal(instance=author)
    postform = CheckPostedForm(instance=author, posted=author.posted)
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': author_form, 'formset': formset, 'formtotal': totalform, 'postform': postform})
```

How can i avoid that? What is that i am doing wrong?

[image: Ajax calls]

Comment: Don't run the development server in production. Also post a full stacktrace from where the error occured

Comment: also, since you are not making any changes to the data, why are you making post instead of get requests?

Comment: @e4c5 Good point. I have changed the POST to GET. However, this is still killing the server. I have debug=True, still there is nothing helpful in the stacktace.

Comment: nothing in the error logs?

Comment: No nothing. Simply killed.

Comment: is there a core dump?